# An App ID with Identifier 'xxx.yyy.zzz' is not available. Please enter a different string when submitting new build

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

Here I already added a new version of my app on the iTunesConnect, and the status of the new version is at 'Prepare for Submission'. However, I have a problem with verifying my new build and submitting it to iTunesConnect.

The Error I got is `An App ID with Identifier 'xxx.yyy.zzz' is not available. Please enter a different string`

Here I left out the Bundle Identifier because I do not want to expose my app ID anyway, but I certainly sure that the bundle Identifier, Version, and Build version is exactly the same as what I added to the iTunesConnect (1.20).

I also already archived the app, but got stuck at the verifying process, and got this `An App ID with Identifier 'xxx.yyy.zzz' is not available. Please enter a different string` error.

Is this the proper way to submit a new build to the iTunesConnect? I think the system should match the App Bundle ID with the one registered at the iTunesConnect's database, and simply verify and upload a new build for me. I do not really know what is wrong here. It seems that the XCode is trying submit the new app, but cannot go through because the Bundle ID is already registered (with the previous version).

Comment: can you show screen shot of error for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the certificate and the AppId

Comment: I did already. I revoked my cert, downloaded a new one, and still got stuck with the issue. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. Closing Xcode.
2. Opening the keychain，deleting the certificate with the corresponding key string.
3. Opening Xcode, Preferences -> View Details -> Reset Certificate
4. Choosing the right certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Let XCode automatically manage the certificates and profiles to use:

- on the `Project Navigator` click on the app
- go to `Build Settings`
- find the `Code Signing` section
- change the `Provisioning Profile` to `Automatic` from the drop-down
- change the `Code Signing Identity` to `iOS Distribution`
- if the project builds without errors, you can `Archive`, `Validate` and `Upload to App Store`
- the build will be available on iTunesConnect

If something is missing XCode will ask to fix it for you.
This is not related to the app version on iTunesConnect.
When submitting a version for review you can chose the build to use.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. Xcode7.2.1. 
[image]

Effective solution is：

[image]